# Postgres constraint invalid after dropping and recreating

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora

We are using postgres Aurora RDS ( version 12.4)

We have a table on which we had a unique constraint on three columns (Column_a , column_b, column_c). After some time ,we realized we would need to add one more column to the unique constraint while the table already had some data.

So we decided to drop the constraint and recreate it with the new set of columns. The following are the statements used:

```
alter table table_name drop constraint constraint_name ;


ALTER TABLE ONLY table_name
  ADD  unique constraint  constraint_name (  column_new ,column_a, column_b , column_c) ;
```

After recreating the constraint the constraint is shown as invalid and on conflict statements using this constraint are failing with an error message:

> "there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification"

We tried creating a duplicate table . We could not replicate the problem when this backup table had no data . But on filling in some data into the table and trying  the same steps we could replicate the problem . The new constraint was showing as invalid .

We would like to understand what causes the constraint to be invalid. Is there any restriction on dropping constraints on tables already having data? We would like to know if we could overcome this without truncating the table.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. The correct syntax to add the constraint would be "ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE (column1, column2, ... column_n);". You can create a new table with the desired structure and constraint and then move the data to the new table using "INSERT into new_table SELECT * FROM old_table;". This seems in the current situation the fastest way to avoid time consuming DB operations on the old table.

Comment: It is not the new constraint that has the problem. Post (or at least check) the *INSERT* statement containing the *on conflict* clause.  It cannot be determined as you did not post it but it is likely it no longer matches  the column list or contain the appropriate 4 columns to detect the conflict.